# How to find an AF_UNIX socket and see the information passing through it?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, freebsd

There is an application running on a `FreeBSD 10.1 release` operating system and i need to figure out how to find the sockets it has created and is using. I know that i'm looking for an `AF_MAP` socket which should be similar to a `AF_UNIX` socket.

How do i see what sockets are open, and once i find the one im looking for i need to see what information passes through. how is this also done?
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on FreeBSD specifically but you can use `lsof` in a way like:

```
$ lsof -p $(pidof your-appname)
```

This will give you all the files it has opened.
For `AF_UNIX` sockets you may refer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/whos-got-the-other-end-of-this-unix-socketpair/190606#190606).

Also, you may want to use `netstat -xa` to see `CONNECTED` state sockets (if the application uses stream oriented sockets)

Comment: ok cool. i foung the location of the socket when opend which is in "/var/hylisphv/sockets/cp_KYtCyz". How do i listen/sniff this socket and see what information is passing within?

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://superuser.com/a/484697/289200 or http://www.humbug.in/2013/sniffing-unix-domain-sockets/